Resolution error when creating Route53 alias record for API gateway
My stack looks like this:
log_group = logs.LogGroup(
    self,
    "APIGatewayLogGroup",
    retention=logs.RetentionDays.ONE_MONTH,
)

hosted_zone_id = Fn.import_value(self.config.hosted_zone_id_export_name)

hosted_zone = route53.HostedZone.from_hosted_zone_attributes(
    self,
    "HostedZone",
    hosted_zone_id=hosted_zone_id,
    zone_name=self.config.base_domain
)

certificate = acm.Certificate(
    self,
    "Certificate",
    domain_name=self.config.domain,
    validation=acm.CertificateValidation.from_dns(hosted_zone),
)

api = apigateway.RestApi(
    self,
    self.api_name,
    rest_api_name=self.api_name,
    description="API Gateway for APIs",
    cloud_watch_role=True,
    deploy=True,
    deploy_options=apigateway.StageOptions(
        access_log_destination=apigateway.LogGroupLogDestination(log_group),
        access_log_format=apigateway.AccessLogFormat.clf(),
        data_trace_enabled=True,
        logging_level=apigateway.MethodLoggingLevel.INFO,
        metrics_enabled=True,
    ),
    default_method_options=apigateway.MethodOptions(
        authorizer=self.authorizer,
        authorization_type=apigateway.AuthorizationType.CUSTOM,
    ),
    default_cors_preflight_options=apigateway.CorsOptions(
        allow_origins=self.config.get_config("API_GATEWAY_CORS_ALLOW_ORIGINS"),
        allow_methods=["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    ),
    domain_name=apigateway.DomainNameOptions(
        domain_name=self.config.domain,
        certificate=certificate,
        endpoint_type=apigateway.EndpointType.EDGE,
        security_policy=apigateway.SecurityPolicy.TLS_1_2
    )
)

route53.RecordSet(
    self,
    "ARecord",
    record_type=route53.RecordType.A,
    zone=hosted_zone,
    target=route53.RecordTarget.from_alias(targets.ApiGateway(api)),
)

When running CDK synth or deploy, I get this error
RuntimeError: Error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Trying to resolve() a Construct at /Resources/${Token[ApiStack.ARecord.Resource.LogicalID.843]}/Properties/aliasTarget/role/node..

I tried an alternative approach where I created the API in one stack, exported the ID, and created the record set in a separate stack using the imported ID. I got exactly the same error.
CDK version: 2.147.0 and aws-cdk-lib==2.147.0
